# OpenVPN not creating default route on Fedora 21

Tags: fedora

On Fedora 21 I'm not getting a new default route set when I establish an OpenVPN connection. On Fedora 20 it was fine (with the exact same .ovpn configuration file).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your .ovpn configuration file.

route-delay 5

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this myself. In my .ovpn client config file, I have `redirect-gateway def1`, yet `route -n` still showed my default route was not changed.

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    1024   0        0 em1
10.1.0.0        172.22.22.57    255.255.0.0     UG    20     0        0 tun0
```

A `traceroute` verified this. So I found a workaround to manually create the route for now. Below, the first line shows how to construct the needed command, and the second one is an example command based on my example route output above.

```bash
sudo route add -net {Destination1} netmask {Genmask1} gw {Gateway2} dev {Iface2}
sudo route add -net 0.0.0.0 netmask 0.0.0.0 gw 172.22.22.57 dev tun0
```

When you're done with VPN, run the same thing again, except with `add` replaced by `del`.

```bash
sudo route del -net 0.0.0.0 netmask 0.0.0.0 gw 172.22.22.57 dev tun0
```

I don't know why OpenVPN's behavior changed. I did try going to Fedora's Settings > Network > Wired > gear > IPv4 > Routes and turning off Automatic, but that did not help.